# Questions about Application.CommonAppDataPath and Application.CommonAppDataRegistry

Tags: registry, privileges

My Windows Forms app's been running under user as Administrator but now I want to try to lower the requirement to Authenticated User.

To date, as administrator, my app's been writing settings in the HKLM_ section of the registry.
It also uses some subdirectories off to store images from scanners/cameras/database, plus file dumps, temp files etc etc. (I have a hatred of "best practice" ideas that want us to store data files in locations external to that of the application folder space as they seem to encourage orphaned data/temp files).

I'm not having much luck finding decent articles about permissions / privileges.

I've found Application.CommonAppDataPath and Application.CommonAppDataRegistry which seem ideal ("Base Path\CompanyName\ProductName\ProductVersion"), but what are the implications of having the file version as part of the returned path?

What I mean is, if the application's updated then won't this cause settings to be lost each installation?

If this path were queried then another value that had product version (File version) segment of the address removed, then I assume that privileges would be lost

If this is true, then what do other devs do to maintain settings between old and new versions of application, especially if there might be any number of old versions all with their own locations because of this "ProductVersion" section of the path? (Hope you understand what I'm getting at)